# enable asp.net DropDownList control using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net

Greeting.

How to enable or disable asp.net DropDownList control using jquery when checking an asp.net checkbox.

So I have I have an asp.net checkbox when I check it I want to enable/disable a DropDownList.

Thank you,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this could do the magic

```
$('#<%= CheckBox1.ClientID %>').click(function(){
  if ($('#<%= DropDownList2.ClientID %>').prop('disabled') != true)
    $('#<%= DropDownList2.ClientID %>').prop('disabled', true);
  else
    $('#<%= DropDownList2.ClientID %>').prop('disabled', false);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#'<%=CheckBoxId.ClientID %>'").click(function(){
    if( $("#'<%=CheckBoxId.ClientID %>'").attr('checked'))
       $("#'<%=DropDownListID.ClientID %>'").attr('disabled', true);
    else
       $("#'<%=DropDownListID.ClientID %>'").attr('disabled', false);
 });
```